# SSH forward from public EC2 to RDS not working

Tags: ssh, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh-tunnel, rds

So I am relatively new to the networking aspects of AWS and am having a problem.  Here is a short description of what I have.

I have a RDS that is not publicly accessible.  The endpoint resolves to a private 10.X.X.X IP.  I have an EC2 instance that is in the same VPC/subnet and is publicly accessible.  I can SSH to this EC2 instance with no problems.  Oddly, I have a process running on that EC2 instance that is able to successfully connect to RDS via JDBC.

However, since the RDS instance is not publicly accessible I want to use the EC2 instance to access the RDS instance from my dev PC.  Everytime I do, I get "channel 2: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed" on my PC.

Here is my command

```
ssh -i ~/key.pem -N -L 3307:rds-name-here.abcdefghi123.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306 ec2-user@1.1.1.1
```

Obviously I changed the details but thats the jist of the command. This is the only error I am getting and really don't know where else to look.

Any pointers in the right direction would he helpful.  I am at a loss at the moment.  I did confirm the security groups allow all traffic to and from each other.  I did not modify the Network ACLs at all.

EDIT: I enabled some debug flags ( -vvv ) and it is responding with packet type 92?

```
debug2: fd 6 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug2: fd 6 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 6 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 2: new [direct-tcpip]
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug3: receive packet: type 92
channel 2: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed
debug2: channel 2: zombie
debug2: channel 2: garbage collecting
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found the answer... apparently it was a typo.  I found another post telling me to look in /var/log/secure and there were errors there about not being able to find the endpoint.  My problem is I was using the endpoint of an old replica read node that I used initially to see the data in my master, that has since been deleted.  I didn't realize it because the full hostname is near identical and thought I had copied/pasted it.

So for other people that are looking into potential problems, check /var/log/secure, grep it for sshd and look for errors "Name or service not known".  That is what was happening to me.

It works now.

Comment: Using Debian Strech here. The relevant logfile is /var/log/auth.log. In my case it showed a lot of lines with "error: connect_to {host}: unknown host (Name or service not known)"

Answer (score 1):

check /etc/ssh/sshd_config

You probably have tunneling disabled:

AllowTcpForwarding no

needs to be

AllowTcpForwarding yes

Comment: Nope just checked, both machines have this set.  I don't think there is any secret information so I pasted it [here](https://pastebin.com/uVy8mpd6) for review incase something else could be causing it.  It expires in 2 weeks, and the config file for the EC2 instance.